# kafka コンシューマーグループの設定

Tags: linux

#### 背景

既存の環境に、いくつかコンシューマーグループが存在します。しかし、既存のコンシューマーグループがどの様な方法で定義されているのかが不明です。
新規のコンシューマーグループを登録する目的で、以下コマンドで、テスト用のコンシューマーグループを登録しようとした所、コマンドを実行したセッションが、実行中のままとなりました。他セッションから確認すると、コンシューマーグループは登録された状態となっていました。
実行中のままとなったコマンドを中断しましたが、テスト用のコンシューマーグループは残ったままとなっていた為、削除コマンドで削除をおこないました。

#### コマンド

`bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic testtp --from-beginning --group test-group`

#### 質問１

宛先host名、宛先IP address、CLIENT-ID 等の設定方法をご教授ください。

#### 質問２

上記のコマンド以外でコンシューマーグループを作成および設定する方法について、ご教授ください。

#### 質問３

上記のコマンド実行時、実行中のままとなった理由について、ご教授ください。（実行中のままとなる事で、何かの機能を提供していたりするのかどうか）